# How do I specify module version constraints for module dependent on another module?

Tags: terraform

I have a [Terraform Module for Docker Swarm](https://github.com/trajano/terraform-docker-swarm-aws) which I reference in another module which I then use in my environment specific Terraform.  I recently published a small fix for it, is it possible to specify the version I want for the module?

I saw it can be done on the providers, but I can't seem to find the equivalent for modules.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading the module from a Git repository, you specify the version as part of the `source` attribute in the `module` block.

If you are loading the module from the Terraform module repository, you specify the version by adding a `version` attribute in the `module` block.

This is all documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources).